# Laravel 6 - Decrement Product when Sold

Tags: php, laravel

I want to track products in stock for every sold. I have `Sale` and `Product` table that `Many-to-Many` to each other.

[image]

**`In Product Model`**

```
    public function sales()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Sale::class)->withPivot('quantity', 'unit_price');
    }
```

**`In Sale Model`**

```
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class)->withPivot('quantity', 'unit_price');
    }
```

**`In SaleController`**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        ...

        foreach($sale->products as $sale) {
            $product = Product::find($sale->id);
            $product->decrement('unit', $sale->pivot->quantity);
        } 

        return response()->json(['updated' => true]);
    }
```

Yes, it work but, the Problem is > **Ex.** I have 10 product when add sale 2, product remain 8, but when I edit that sale to 1, product in stock remain 7

It doesn't make sense the **Product Unit** should be `8` not `7`.

Any help?? 
Thanks

Comment: __decrement__ decreases value, means __substracts__. If you need to increase (add/plus some value) - use __increment__.

Comment: So your code snippets shows how you calculate the `remain` value before the edit. But how do you do the edit?

Comment: sorry, but do u catch what i mean?? @shaedrich

Comment: I don't know. That's why I ask for more information because it's hard to follow the process with just four lines of code.

Comment: @shaedrich i mean do u catch what my problem is???

Comment: Instead of asking the same question over and over again rather than answering my request for clarification I would be very pleased if you can provide more details so that I can *catch what your problem is*. I hope, you understand, that I *do* want to understand it.

Comment: @shaedrich i updated my question, pls take alook..

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more than this, I've two approaches:

1. UPDATE the `remain` value relatively:

   - get previous quantity
   - Subtract new quantity
   - If the result is positive, subtract it from the `remain` value
   - If it is negative, add it to the `remain` value
2. Recalculate the `remain` value

   - UPDATE the `sale` table **without** changing the `remain` value
   - Get the current `products` from the `sales` table and calculate the `remain` value based on the current `quantity` values

Answer (score 0):

for decrement or subtract, you can use

```
$product->decrement('unit', $sale->pivot->quantity);
```

for incrementing or add, use

```
$product->increment('unit', $sale->pivot->quantity);
```